# Reusing a Prepared Statement with another conneciton object

Tags: java, prepared-statement, jtds

Here is my setup:

I have two databases, lets say *DB A* and *DB B*.

I have a `Connection` to *DB A* called `conn_a`. I create a `PreparedStatement` such as

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = conn_a.prepareStatement(sql,
    Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Then I do a bunch of 'set' operation on the `pStmt`; such as `setInt`, `setString` etc.

Finally, I execute the statement with `pStmt.execute();`

Now I want to run the SAME prepared statement (`pStmt`) on `conn_b` (hooked up to *DB B*). How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Each `PreparedStatement` is linked to the `Connection` it was created from.

Comment: Just do the exact same thing, but using conn_b.prepareStatement() instead of conn_a.prepareStatement().

Comment: @JBNizet I was trying to see if I can reuse the prepared statement object. My above example is too simplistic; in a real world scenario; the 'sync' between db_a/db_b are done in different places. I was hoping to just pass along the Prepared statement object instead of re-doing everything.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That's what I figured; but wanted to see if there is a way to get around this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can - you prepare the statement against a connection and, by extension, against a database. The intention is that the query execution plan is cached at the server side so that subsequent executions of the prepared statement don't have to re-evaluate the query plan again. Running the same PreparedStatement against a different database doesn't make sense in that context.

You *can* prepare the statement again, against the other connection, but it would be a different prepared statement, albeit one that was extremely similar to the first one. So it's not hard to envisage a method where you pass the connection to it, and prepare the statement against the provided connection.